# page.click function does not wait till page.waitForResponse completes

Tags: typescript, testing, automation, jestjs, puppeteer

I have my code set up like this

```
  1. await page.click(selectors.login.submit)
  2. await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil:'networkidle0'})
  3. await page.click(selectors.transation.navLink)
  4. await page.waitForResponse(response => response.ok())
  5. await page.click(selectors.transation.addNew)
```

Here, line 5 does not wait till line 4 completes all the response.

I have already tried using

```
Promise.all([
page.click(selectors.transation.navLink)
await page.waitForResponse(response => response.ok())
])
```

thinking that all the scripts inside promise executes first before going to line 5 but due to some reason it just doesn't happens as it supposed to happen.

I even tried using the `await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil:'networkidle0'})` instead of `await page.waitForResponse(response => response.ok())` thinking that would help but it acts exactly as same

The expected result should be executing the `page.waitfor` function first, let all the request complete and then go on the `page.click` function.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the `page.waitForNavigation()` in your `Promise.all()` as mentioned in the docs for `page.click()`. See https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-pageclickselector-options:

```
await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(waitOptions),
    page.click(selectors.transation.navLink)
]);
```

You appear to missing the `await` before your `Promise.all()`, and you have an extra `await` before your `page.waitForResponse()`. In my experience, this extra `await` will cause the code to error out when run.

Maybe relevant depending on your setup: I've found that for clicks that cause a full page navigation (where the page actually reloads), that `page.waitForNavigation(waitOptions)` is needed, whereas for clicks that just call an XHR (shows up on network tab rather than doing a full page reload) that `await page.waitForResponse(response => response.ok())` is best.